# Why electromagnetic force works even in the absence of light?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

1. Why electromagnetic force works even in a dark room constructed of thick concrete walls?
2. If photons do not enter Earth’s core, why rocks, silicon, magma, iron, oxygen, are present there which requires electromagnetic force for atomic bonding?
3. Each night, when we are completely opposite of the Sun (em radiation source), why we experience our existence? I mean, should this not turn off electromagnetic force, if we are in a completely dark room every midnight?

Extra note -
I have spent many days to find the answer to this question on internet, but unfortunately i couldn’t. So any help from an expert will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is visible light the only type of light that the E&M force can generate? Or are there other types of light?

Comment: The electromagnetic force is not just visible light and not just from the sun. For example, a magnet creates its own magnetic field. It doesn't require the sun. Light from the sun is just one form of electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos 11 Of course there are other wavelengths (radio, micro, infrared, ultraviolet, x rays, gamma rays) of em force.

Comment: @rghome 10 So according to you, any charged particle can creates it’s own magnetic field without the need of a photon? Am i right?

Comment: A changing electric field (e.g., a moving charged particle) creates a magnetic field. A changing electric field creates a magnetic field and so on. That is what an electromagnetic wave is. A photon can be thought of as a packet of an EM wave at some point where it is measured. The answer by Árpád Szendrei gives more detail and explains about static fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very important to understand the difference between electromagnetic waves and static electromagnetic fields.

You are asking about why rocks are intact without visible light, and the answer is that the EM force that is needed to hold material like rocks (and give covalent bonding for their molecules) together is represented by static EM fields that are existing around the electrons (and protons too) inside the molecule. These static EM fields are modeled in math by virtual photons. These are not real photons, they are just a mathematical tool to describe the phenomenon of static EM fields.

> An electromagnetic field (also EMF or EM field) is a magnetic field produced by moving electrically charged objects.[1] It affects the behavior of non-comoving charged objects at any distance of the field. The electromagnetic field extends indefinitely throughout space and describes the electromagnetic interaction. It is one of the four fundamental forces of nature (the others are gravitation, weak interaction and strong interaction).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_field

Now EM waves are made up of real photons, and these photons (that you mention too) are transferring EM energy throughout space. These photons can have all kinds of wavelengths, including visible light and non-visible light.

> In physics, electromagnetic radiation (EM radiation or EMR) refers to the waves (or their quanta, photons) of the electromagnetic field, propagating (radiating) through space, carrying electromagnetic radiant energy.[1]
>   In quantum mechanics, an alternate way of viewing EMR is that it consists of photons, uncharged elementary particles with zero rest mass which are the quanta of the electromagnetic force, responsible for all electromagnetic interactions.[6]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation

And it is very important to understand that light is part visible, and part non-visible light, both are the same kind of EM waves.

Now you are saying that at night, when there is no visible light here on Earth coming directly from the Sun, the EM force should turn off. But the EM force itself that is represented by static EM fields does not need the Sunlight. The EM force (field) itself  exist throughout space even without energy from the Sun.

Comment: Do you mean, static EM field of an electron or a proton, is produced by a virtual photon? I was assuming, a real photon excites an electron from it’s ground state to a higher orbit/shell and as it returns to it’s ground state, this movement of an electron produces the EM field around it. Is it possible that the spin of any charged particle (electron or proton) can produce static EM field?

In reference of EM waves i want to know that, “Can extra low frequency electromagnetic wave can pass through Earth?”

Comment: @user248881 a static EM field is just modeled in math by virtual photons, these virtual photons are just a model in math. When a real photon excites an electron, and then the electron relaxes, it emits a real photon (EM wave). An electron has a static EM field around it as an intrinsic property.

Comment: Can you please explain me, how an electron develops a static EM field around it without any motion? And can ‘extra low frequency’ (3 Hz to 30 Hz) electromagnetic waves pass through the Earth as it has wavelength of 100,000 to 10,000 kilometers?

Comment: @user248881 electrons static electric field is due to their intrinsic properties, and it came into existence the same time the electron itself came to existence. What you are referring to, is an accelerating electron (emitting EM waves, real photons). ELF EM waves can penetrate water, but not Earth, but that should be a separate question.

Comment: So absorption and emission of a photon by an electron, is only for seeing things around us? Do electrons never absorb and emit photons of other frequency than the visible spectrum?

Comment: @user248881 no, emission and absorption is for all wavelengths, like visible, non-visible, IR, unltraviolet, radio, etc. But an electron can emit/absorb a photon when it is bound to an atom, or when a free electron (in a metal) is accelerating.

Comment: Does this absorption and emission of photons by electrons of an atom happens only within 7 shells or does an electron reachs even higher shell? Thank you very much for helping me Mr. Árpád Szendrei

Comment: @user248881 "The element with highest known atomic number is 118 (Ununoctium - Uuo). Its electronic configuration is [Rn]5f146d107s27p6 meaning, its outermost shell in its ground state is 7. Therefore, the highest number of shells an atom can have in its ground state is 7 as of now. But Uuo is the final element in the seventh row (period). Element #119, if/when it is discovered, will be a member of the 8th period which will have 8 shells in its ground state.
Excited states are a different story. An atom can be excited to higher states such that its electrons occupy arbitrarily high shells."

Answer (score -1):

All light waves and all radio waves have reflections.  Both light waves and radio waves reach inside of the room, if there is a possibility to come inside through reflections.  Our eyes may not be able such reflected light but ordinary antenna sensors may be able to observe such reflected such reflected radio waves.  If reflection is not possible it is very difficult even for radio waves to get inside.  For example, it is always challenging task to have radio communications with submarines which are immersed in sea water.

Answer (score -3):

> 1. Why electromagnetic force works even in a dark room constructed of thick concrete walls?

The since about electromagnetic interactions is divided into three parts

- electric interactions (electrostatics)
- magnetic interactions (magnetostatics) and
- electromagnetic interactions

The last is about

- moving charges and magnetic fields (Lorentz force in the form of induction of electric fields (the movement of conductor through a magnetic field, the practical device is the electric generator),
- kinetic energy (a wire with alternating current inside a magnetic field, a practical device is the electric motor for example) and
- magnetic fields (a current carrying coil, where the charges get accelerated due to the their movement in circles along the coil).

Last not least there is another phenomenon. Everything around us is emitting and absorbing photons. Even in dark rooms. As long, as the temperature is above absolute zero Kelvin, all around us is involved in the process of equilibrating their temperatures. Imagine an atom at room temperature and around empty room. The atom will emit photons until its temperature will reach zero Kelvin. The emitted photons are going simply away forever. From the cold death we are save only because we receive continuously photons from the surrounding. From warm walls of your room you receive more photons (in the infrared) as from cold walls. BTW, the infrared you can observe with a IR camera.

> 2. If photons do not enter Earth’s core, why rocks, silicon, magma, iron, oxygen, are present there which requires electromagnetic force for atomic bonding?

The atomic bonding is higher in the case of low photon absorption. Electric and magnetic forces are responsible for the bonding. With electromagnetic radiation (a stream of photons) one is able to destroy atomic bonding.

> 3. Each night, when we are completely opposite of the Sun (em radiation source), why we experience our existence? I mean, should this not turn off electromagnetic force, if we are in a completely dark room every midnight?

We are adopted to the conditions on earth. And by technical help (cloves, fire, house, ...) we are able to survive even at low temperatures. As a counterexample take the free space a good. A human, facing the sun, would be heated from the sun very fast to dangerous temperatures. Meanwhile his back side will emit so much EM radiation without receiving remarkable amount, that the back side will be frozen shortly.